# Windows desktop: open new app in current desktop instead of switching to a desktop where the app is opened

Tags: windows, pdf, virtual-desktop

When I open a pdf file, if I already have a pdf app opened in another virtual desktop, the system will bring me to that desktop and open the file in the same app. Is there a way for me to open a new instance of that pdf app and stay in the current virtual desktop?

Comment: I assume you want to have this so you can be in explorer and not get the annoyance of being switched away from your desktop. Consider using the Preview pane in explorer so you click the pdf, and see it in the preview pane without opening it. That way, it stays with you.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could explain this but not for one specific app instead of for all the apps. It is annoying that Windows move me out of the current Desktop where I am working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Windows applications allow you to run multiple instances, each of which opens on the current desktop.  For example, Foxit Reader 9 (PDF viewer) lets you specify `Preferences > Documents > Open Settings > [x] Allow multiple instances`.  Some applications, such as MS-Word and Excel, support a command-line option which you can add to shortcuts and (in many cases) in `ftype` commands for opening a file type.

To find out whether your PDF app supports multiple instances, check its Settings and Help.  Or you may have to do a web search.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Desktops are a way to organize screens and what shows / does not show.

But Apps are not Desktop specific.  It an App is open, it is open in all Desktops. If you close an App in Desktop A, it is also closed in Desktop B. This is true for Apps that do not allow multiple instances. And so for this type of App, you cannot do what you wish.

If an App has multiple instances available to it, then you can open it in another desktop, but then both instances are available in all the desktops. You can open (say) DOC A in Desktop A and DOC B in Desktop B but they are not isolated. Everything is available in all Desktops.

That is how Apps work in Windows Desktops. There is no true isolation between Windows Desktops.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but its not entirely correct. If an app does not allow multiple instances, it will never work. If an app does allow multiple instances, it can be done. If the app supports multiple instances, then you likely have to open the app manually first, switch to that instance first (aka have it been active) then open the pdf. For example, Vivaldi Browser can have multiple profiles and multiple instances of the program open, and if you open a file (can be PDF) it will always open in the last active window as a new tab. This workaround ca be the answer here.

Comment: Good point and I clarified my answer to include multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John! It is good to know the theories behind. I will choose the other answer for now because that solved my problem, though only for pdf files only.